# How to select columns based on string using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I can select and rename the column name like this without any problem:

```r
library(tidyverse)
iris <- as.tibble(iris)
iris %>% select(sepal_ln = Sepal.Length, sepal_wd = Sepal.Width)
#> # A tibble: 150 × 2
#>    sepal_ln sepal_wd
#>       <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1       5.1      3.5
#> 2       4.9      3.0
#> 3       4.7      3.2
#> 4       4.6      3.1
#> 5       5.0      3.6
#> 6       5.4      3.9
#> 7       4.6      3.4
#> 8       5.0      3.4
#> 9       4.4      2.9
#> 10      4.9      3.1
#> # ... with 140 more rows
```

But want I want do to do is to call the column from string instead of column name. I tried the following but it failed:

```r
> wanted <- "Sepal"
> iris %>% select(sepal_ln = !! paste0(wanted,".Length"), 
+                 sepal_wd = !! paste0(wanted,".Width"), 
+ )
Error: "Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width": must resolve to integer column positions, not string
>
```

What's the right way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `select_`

```
 iris %>% 
   select_(sepal_ln = paste0(wanted, ".Length"), paste0(wanted, ".Width"))
```

Also, there are wrappers within `select` to do this more easily i.e. `one_of`, `contains`, `matches` etc. to select the required columns from the data

```
iris %>% 
  select(setNames(one_of(paste0(wanted, c(".Length", ".Width"))),
                 c("sepal_ln", "sepal_wd"))) %>%
  head(2)
# A tibble: 2 × 2
#   sepal_ln sepal_wd
#     <dbl>    <dbl>
#1      5.1      3.5
#2      4.9      3.0
```

NOTE: It is not clear whether the `select_` methods will get deprecated in the next `dplyr` release (`0.6.0`) or not.